# opendns and perl lwp::simple get

Tags: perl, security, get, dns, filtering

I am trying to filter web content that is accessed programmatically, lets say through lwp::simple or sockets.

I do not have any control over the server configuration, eg. dns settings

How will I be able to use opendns, with these restrictions.

is there per-request dns?

I am not that familiar with this topic, and I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Is "programmatically" an important condition? There is no reliable way to determine whether a resolver request is driven by a user or some automation.

Answer (score 1):

LWP/Perl sockets use the operating system's resolver only. You need to set up a separate forwarder (e.g. [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html)) somewhere that can be configured to resolve certain hostname differently. Then either:

- subclass LWP to use the external forwarder or
- get permission to point the OS resolver there or
- write something in C that hi-jacks the getnameinfo(3)/gethostbyaddr(3) and related system calls, then install this as [preload hack](http://enwp.org/Dynamic_linker#ELF-based_Unix-like_systems).